# Javascript Confirm Box not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple html form. When the user click on the submit button, a message should pop up to confirm the submission. If the the user click on Ok, the form should be submitted. If the user click on Cancel, it should return to the page and do nothing. Following is my submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="" onclick="confirm('Are you sure to insert
data?');">
```

Now the problem here is that the form is submitted even if the user click on Cancel.

Please Help.

Comment: just use `return` infront of your `confirm`

Answer (score 6):

The `confirm()` statement only evaluates to an expression, `true` or `false`. To make it not submit the form, you need it to *return* the value.

i.e., this would translate to:

```
<input type="submit" name="" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to insert data?');">
```